# Text not appearing in UITextView in IOS 5.0 and later

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

I am working on a iPad application where i am entering some dynamic text into UITextView. It is working fine if i test it on below ios 5.0. But if i test it on ios 5.0 or later, text is not appearing/visible. I have tried with the different font colors too. Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please give your working code, so that we can trace the problem

Comment: This seems like problem in ios 5.1. When text in UITextView turned to multiple line, text starts appearing.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was working on a project and ran into the same thing. In iOS versions other than 5, the UITextView worked perfectly. But, on 5, the text just simply wouldn't show up. I did possibly the hackiest thing ever to fix it. I made the parent view a UITextView delegate, and in the textViewDidChange method of that view, I added the code:

```
textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@",textView.text];
textView.text = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:@""];
```

This is basically a joke as far as a fix goes. That said, just quickly making it multiline and then single line fixed the problem. I'm quite sure this isn't the *correct* answer to this problem, but hopefully it helps someone figure out how to handle this in a pinch.